# Xamarin WebView - using keyboard

Tags: xamarin, webview, keyboard

I have a Xamarin.Forms App, which display only webView, is it possible to use a keyboard(like a normal physical keyboard) to for example type in google search?

I searched the internet and didnt find any solution, and it's very important to me to have this funcionality.

in simple words.
I run some page in Xamarin.Forms.WebView and i want to have possibility to type some other URL by outside keyboard.

Comment: Could you please describe the specific error code that appeared?

Comment: There is no error. I lunch Application and it showing me for example www.google.com via webview, and when i try fill textbox by my PC keyboard it's not working im only allowed to use Android Keyboard

Comment: If it's just a simple webview, PC keyboard input is allowed.

Comment: So why i can't  do it?

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here.

Comment: Sure!
https://github.com/RafalWolf94/XamarinApp 
Here you go, really thank you for  helping!

Answer (score 0):

- I downloaded your code and tested it.

  Hereis the running screenshot(Use PC keyboard input):

[image]

- You can create an empty project and use webview to re-test to see the
  results.
- For more information about WebView, you can check
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos